# Remote MYSQL Performance

Tags: mysql, mariadb

please note that I'm working on a problem for 2 weeks and I didnt find its solution. I had a running website on Joomla and the Joomla + MYSQL are installed on the same server.
So, I separated the app server (Joomla) and the mysql on a different server on AWS using the same network and copied the same configuration of my.cnf from the old server to the old server.
My problem now that I dont see the mysql is using more than 3 GB RAM from the server which has specs 32GB RAM and when I do like 100 connection at the same time on the website, joomla breaks the connection with mysql db and I dont find any error relate
d to this case in the mysql error log or in the aborted connection history in mysql

pool size: 32GB
pool instances: 50

Answer (score 1):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of RAM.  Setting it to the same as RAM may lead to a lot of swapping, which is *terrible* for performance.